# Finding pathways in python while using parallel for a dual platform

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I've been trying to learn python and while making a rather simple program to try and list all the files in a folder I came across a problem of the program not recognizing the path I had entered.  I'm running it in Windows using parallels on my Mac and no matter what I try I have not been able to get the code to work.  I even used os.path code to find the pathway which it did, but then didn't recognize the path it had found.  Does anyone know if there is something i am missing?
This is the code I've been using:

```
import os 
def rename_files():    
   file_list = os.listdir("//Mac/Home/Desktop/python/prank")
   print (file_list)

rename_files()
```

Comment: What is `//`? Doesn't seem valid. Provide a full path.

Comment: When I had python find the pathway the "//Mac/Home...." was the way it came out.  I've also tried it with jus one "/" and reversed the slashes, as well as tried it with: r"/Mac/Home...." (also with variations with the slashes.